# How to publish a JAX WS on Tomcat with the URL like localhost:8088

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I got a web service running on Tomcat, and everything works fine. My web service can be accessed via `http:/ipaddress:8080/XXXX/YYYY`. Now, the client claimed that for some reason, they only can access the URL like `http:/ipaddress:8080`. They want the request to `http:/ipaddress:8080` still can be 'routed' to my web service. I don't know how to achieve that, can anybody help me on this?

Comment: best thing to do is have an apache server running in front of tomcat, speaking to it via ajp / routing requests; you could set up a redirect or something.

Comment: Are you sure there are only single slashes `/` in your URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your web application the root Tomcat application (you will have to name your war ROOT.war and replace whatever ROOT directory already exists).  This will get rid of the XXXX.  You could then add a servlet-mapping to your web.xml like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Make sure you don't include any * characters in your url-pattern, just the single forward slash.  Tomcat should in theory map any requests that don't match a URL to that servlet.  I've never tried it but it might allow you to do what you want.